# MultiValueDictKeyError at edit

Tags: python, html, django

I writing code for my class to create a list from the user's input. On the list there is an option for editing each entry. However, when I click on my edit button I get multi value error. Could anyone please let me know how to fix this error?

My HTML part for the list:*

```html
<h5>Your wish list:</h5>

<table>
  <thead style="background-color: rgb(226, 220, 220)">
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Date added</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for wish in all_wishes %}
    <tr>
      <td><h5><a href="/wishes/{{wish.id}}">{{wish.wish}}</a></h5></td>
      <td> Added on {{wish.created_at}} </td>
      <td> <a href="/wishes/{{wish.id}}/delete" role="button">Remove</a> | <a href="/wishes/{{wish.id}}/edit">Edit</a>  | <a href="/wishes/{{wish.id}}/granted" role="button">Granted!</a> 
      </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My urls:

```py
#### I removed other URLs to make it clean here 

from django.urls import path
from .import views


urlpatterns = [
    path("wishes/<int:wish_id>/edit", views.edit),
]
```

My `views.py` (edit part):

```py
def edit(request, wish_id):
    wish = Wish.objects.get(id=wish_id)
    wish.description = request.POST['description']
    wish.save()
    return redirect("wishes/showall.html")
```

Redirect to HTML on top.

My Model:

```py
class Wish(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

My error message:

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /wishes/32/edit
'description'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/wishes/32/edit
Django Version: 2.2
Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value:    'description'

C:\Users\wishlist_app\views.py in edit
    wish.description = request.POST['description']
```

Comment: You made a GET request, not a POST request.

Comment: I put it as request.POST. isnt it POST request?

Comment: No, loook at the *Request Method* part, you made a GET request. You should wrap the the items of the form in a `<form method="post" action="...">` part, with as action the URL to make a POST request to.